# Data Connection Library Type is Missing in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: data-connection

I have **Sharepoint 2010 Foundation** installed in **Windows 7 Professional**(64 bit). Now I noticed that **Data Connection Library** type is missing in library templates. Do I have to make any changes in my current settings or is it not available with **Foundation** package?

I am a beginner in Sharepoint, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please check this [Missing Data Connection Library In SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/21/missing-data-connection-library-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Data Connection Library isn't included in Foundation.

But the two features regarding Data Connection Libraries are included in Search Server Express, but not installed (and therefore not activated), by default. Probably because the OOTB functionality that uses them isn't in Foundation.

You can install the feature by executing the following commands in "SharePoint 2010 Management Shell":

```
Install-SPFeature DataconnectionLibrary
Install-SPFeature DataconnectionLibraryStapling
```

That'll make it available on future sites.

You can then enable it on existing sites by executing this command for each:

```
Enable-SPFeature DataConnectionLibrary -url http://siteurl
```

**Note that using Data Connection Library from Search Server Express in your Foundation Site collections will effectively limit you to running on a single server, as it'll only work on the server with Search Server Express installed**

Comment: thanks, when I execute **Install-SPFeature DataconnectionLibrary** in **Management Shell** it shows an error - Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\DataconnectionLibrary\feature.xml I couldn't find the folder **DataconnectionLibrary** in 14\Template\Features\

Comment: Sorry.The installation I checked had Search Server Express installed. The answer is now updated after checking a pure Foundation installation.

Answer (score -1):

try to enable "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features" !

Comment: The asker has Foundation. How would they enable the Enterprise features? Please try to understand the question.